# How can I get the name of the file I'm uploading

Tags: angular, angular-file-upload

I'm using angular-file-uploader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader) to upload files and it works fine, but I can't find a way to get the filename, I want something like assign it to a variable so I can use to download it later.

I got a component with the following html template:

```
<angular-file-uploader 
    [config]="afuConfig"
    (ApiResponse)="DocUpload($event)">
</angular-file-uploader>
```

and TypeScript:

```
this.afuConfig = {
    uploadAPI: {
        url:"http://localhost:3000/api/containers/container/upload",
    }
};

DocUpload(res){
    console.log(res);
    //I want something like this..
    //console.log(somehow.getFileName())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a selector to the template called `fileUpload1` for example:

```html
<angular-file-uploader
  #fileUpload1
  [config]="afuConfig"
  (ApiResponse)="DocUpload($event)"
></angular-file-uploader>
```

In the TypeScript part of your component you add a ViewChild property to the class:

```js
@ViewChild('fileUpload1')
private fileUpload1: AngularFileUploaderComponent;
```

And finally you can get the file name in the `DocUpload` function like this:

```js
DocUpload(res) {
  console.log(this.fileUpload1.allowedFiles[0].name);
}
```

The `allowedFiles` attribute is an array of all selected files. If you want the first one you have to use `allowedFiles[0]` and then read the name via the `name` attribute.

Comment: Looks about right.. https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader/blob/master/projects/angular-file-uploader/src/lib/angular-file-uploader.component.html